# Math Exercises, Highschool Student

Tags: problem-solving

I really want to improve my problem solving skills..
However I have found that most of the exercise books (lots of problems) are above my curent level (e.g. Olympiad and College)

I am currently in Highschool and would like to know if there are any books and websites (to print out exercise sheets which would enable me to practice maths .

These books can cover a range of diffrent topics (e.g. Algebra, Geometry etc..) but these topics have to be oart of a standard highschool maths education.

I am looking for Math exercise books, with loads of problems at highschol level.

Comment: you should give project euler a try

Comment: The Art of Problem Solving books are generally quite good and high-school level

Answer (score 1):

Although this may not have as many problems as you're looking for https://www.khanacademy.org/math has several helpful videos and questions that test your problem solving skills for each topic

Answer (score 1):

I would give this list a try. The books should be at your level if not just slightly more advanced.

- Challenging Problems in Algebra (Dover Books) by Posamentier
- Problems in Geometry (Dover Books) by Posamentier
- The USSR Olympiad Problem Book: Selected Problems and Theorems of Elementary Mathematics (Dover Books) by Shklarsky, Chentzov, and Yaglom
- 103 Trigonometry Problems: From the Training of the USA IMO Team by Andreescu and Feng
- 104 Number Theory Problems: From the Training of the USA IMO Team by Andreescu
- 105 Algebra Problems from the AwesomeMath Summer Program by Andreescu-
- 106 Geometry Problems from the AwesomeMath Summer Program by Andreescu
- 107 Geometry Problems from the Awesomemath Year-Round Program by Andreescu
- 108 Algebra Problems from the Awesomemath Year-Round Program by Andreescu
- "Problems From the Book" and "Straight From the Book" by Andreescu
- The Stanford Mathematics Problem Book (Dover Books) by Polya and Kilpatrick
  Sequences, Combinations, Limits (Dover Books) by Gelfand, Gerver, Kirillov, Konstantinov, and Kushnirenko
- Challenging Mathematical Problems With Elementary Solutions (Dover Books) by A.M. Yaglom and I.M. Yaglom
- Hungarian Problem Book I-IV containing the Eötvös Mathematical Competitions from 1894–1963